# split a variable with brackets php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to do this once the data is already in my MySQL db but what I'm trying to do is 
I have a variable called `$host` that will always be like            `RockN_Roll_lady (MisFit_kay1)` what I am looking for a point in the right direction is how to make my variable split so that `$host` field will be `RockN_Roll_lady`  and $hostplayername will be `MisFit_kay1`

I know using MySQL it can be done once its inserted   using

```
    Update tourne_report set Host= SUBSTRING_INDEX( Host , '(', 1 ) ,Hostplayername= SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( Host , '(', 2 ),'(',-1) ;
```

but I'm looking for a solution to take the `$host` variable and make it into 2 variables before the data gets entered into my database

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: Will `(` only be use for this single use?  If so, you could split using `explode`, or use regex.

Comment: the data is being  inputted from a form text box the top section of the  data is 

 Nojoks's Tourney Bracket Tool Version 1.2.1.84
Tournament:  HAPPY Dbl Elim Casino
Date:  10/03/2014
Day:  Friday
Scheduled Start:  4:00
Actual Start:  4:00:00 PM
Closed:  4:10:39 PM
Host:  RockN_Roll_lady (MisFit_kay1)
Number of Players:  16

it is passing the start time the host name  the hostplayername  number of players as well as  more info in the rest of the formatting into the database  the brackets arent needed but the () are preformatted in the output I have to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

$str            = "RockN_Roll_lady (MisFit_kay1)";
$arrChunks      = preg_split("#\(#", $str);
$host           = trim($arrChunks[0]);
$hostplayername = trim($arrChunks[1], ")");

var_dump($host);
var_dump($hostplayername);
```

Comment: Why use `preg_split()` instead of `explode()`? You don't have a pattern in the regular expression.

Comment: We just kept it simple. The pattern is just any "(" in the string. Every string in this scenario is theoretically expected to contain "(" and ")". So we split by the first "(" and trim-off the 2nd ")". It makes life easier...

Comment: That doesn't explain why you use `preg_split` to do the split instead of `explode`.

Comment: `$arrChunks = explode('(', $str);` would do the same thing and is simpler.

Comment: @Barman: Yes... you are quite right... i agree...but in the end, both achieves the same result ;-)

Comment: I suggest you only use `preg_match` when you're using a real regular expression pattern. If it's just a simple string delimiter, `explode` is preferable.

Comment: It's more idiomatic, and it's better performance. When I see `preg_match`, it makes me think there's a more complex type of parsing being done than splitting on a single character.

Comment: Why are you having so much trouble spelling my name? Doesn't the automatic completion after `@` work for you?

Comment: LMAO: @Barmar  Excuse me... I got it right this time; i believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
list($host,$hostplayername) = explode(" (", rtrim($host,")"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  either `explode` or `preg_split` on the `space`, i.e.:

[explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$string = "RockN_Roll_lady (MisFit_kay1)";
$result = explode(" ",  preg_replace('/\(|\)/', '', $string));
```

[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$string = "RockN_Roll_lady (MisFit_kay1)";
$result = preg_split('/ /', preg_replace('/\(|\)/', '', $string));
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/6cDN8g)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
preg_match('/^(\w*)\s*\((\w*)\)$/', $host, $match);
$host = $match[1];
$hostplayername = $match[2];
```

`\w*` matches a sequence of alphanumeric and underscore characters, while `\s*` matches a sequence of spaces, and `(...)` puts the parts of the string that match them into capture groups, which are put into the `$match` array.